# best way to pass application token from spring boot backend to angular frontend after OAuth negotiation

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, oauth, microservices

## Architecture:

- frontend: angular application
- backend: spring boot application

## Requirements:

- authenticating user with Google OAuth in backend (because of the need for refresh token), storing the OAuth access token & refresh token in the backend system (for furthur backend operations), along with returning custom (backend generated) token to the frontend for furthur api usages.

## Current Approach:

- launching the google oauth sign-in module from frontend (after clicking on "Login with Google" button) with redirect-url pointing to backend
- fetching the authorizationCode in callback url of the backend (after user consent), along with sending request to Google to obtain "access token" and "refresh token"
- assuming a successful negotiation, the backend will save access/refresh tokens in it's storage. afterwards, the backend should create a custom token for frontend & send it to the angular client. since there's no connection with frontend after completing the OAuth scenario, the question is:  "how should I send the application token to the angular frontend at the end of the OATH negotiation ?"** , what's the best practice for that ?

## Question

since the operation has been taken place in the backend system, the only way I was thinking of was to create custom application token & redirect user with a GET call to the specific angular component (this redirect call will contain the application token (say, within query param)), after that angular component receives the GET call containing the token, it will check the custom token with backend (to ensure about the value), save it into it's localStorage & redirect user to home page.

but I'm not sure, if it's the proper way of handling it (sending application token via a GET call from backend to angular component - which will be visible). is there a better way to handle this ? is there any security issues with the current approach ?